# Using promise to send http request after storage.get

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm running an app in Ionic3 and I'm trying to send the device info through an http request to my API, so I can store it in a table at my SQL database.

Apparently, the tasks are running async, and the SEND method is rushing over the storage.get method (which retrieve info from ionic storage), so it's passing as null or empty

I read over some posts online and tried to build this request into promises, but when testing, it returns me the following error : "cannot read property  'webservice' of undefined  "

here's my code:

```
           public sendDeviceInfo(company: string, worker: string)
{
    this.storage.get(StorageEnum.PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_PLAYERID).then(playerId => {

        const getDeviceInfo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(playerId != null && playerId != '' && typeof playerId != 'undefined') {

            let param = {
                company : company,
                worker  : worker,
                device  : {                    
                    uuid          : playerId
                    ,model        : this.device.model
                    ,manufacturer : this.device.manufacturer
                    ,platform     : this.device.platform
                    ,version      : this.device.version
                }
            };
            resolve(param)                
        } else {
            const err = new Error('Algo deu errado');
            reject(err)
        }
    })

       const sendData = function(param) {

        let deviceInfoObject = this.webservice.saveDeviceInfo(JSON.stringify(param)).subscribe(response => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));

            this.storage.set(StorageEnum.DEVICE_INFO, param); 
            }, err => {                    

                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            })
            return Promise.resolve(deviceInfoObject)
        }

        const deviceInfo = function() {
            getDeviceInfo.then(sendData)
            .then(function(fulfilled) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(fulfilled))
            })
            .catch(err => alert(err.message))
        }

        deviceInfo();
    });
}
```

I want to send the device info ONLY after the storage.get is fulfilled, should I use Promise? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What does `this.storage` represent? It looks like you'll have to promisify this request.

Comment: I updated with my latest tests and added promises to it

Answer (score 0):

After some tests and research, I figured out a solution:

```
    public sendDeviceInfo(company: string, worker: string)
{
    this.storage.get(StorageEnum.PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_PLAYERID).then(playerId => {

    let getDeviceInfo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if(playerId != null && playerId != '' && typeof playerId != 'undefined') {

            let param = {
                company : company,
                worker  : worker,
                device  : {                    
                    uuid          : playerId
                    ,model        : this.device.model
                    ,manufacturer : this.device.manufacturer
                    ,platform     : this.device.platform
                    ,version      : this.device.version
                }
            };
            resolve(param)

        } else {
            const err = new Error('Algo deu errado');
            reject(err)
        }
        }).then((param) => {
            this.webservice.saveDeviceInfo(JSON.stringify(param)).subscribe(response => {

                this.storage.set(StorageEnum.DEVICE_INFO, param); 
                }, err => {                    

                })
            }
        )
    });
}
```

this is the final code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach too with proper error handling and clean flow...

```
public sendDeviceInfo(company: string, worker: string){
    this.storage.get(StorageEnum.PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_PLAYERID)
    .then((playerId)=>{
        if(playerId == null || playerId == '' || typeof playerId == 'undefined') {
            throw new Error("Algo deu errado");
        }
        let param = {
            company : company,
            worker  : worker,
            device  : {                    
                uuid          : playerId
                ,model        : this.device.model
                ,manufacturer : this.device.manufacturer
                ,platform     : this.device.platform
                ,version      : this.device.version
            }
        }            
        return param
    })
    .then((param)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.webservice.saveDeviceInfo(JSON.stringify(param))
            .subscribe((response)=>{
                console.log(response);
                resolve(param)
            },
            (err)=>{
                reject(err)
            })                
          });
    })
    .then((param)=>{
        return this.storage.set(StorageEnum.DEVICE_INFO, param)
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log('error', error)
    })
}
this.sendDeviceInfo('company', 'worker')
```

That's it!

Comment: @Matheus Batista: can you try above approach with proper error handling and clean flow...and let me know if it works for you